# How do I add a row to check if it exist or not?

Tags: sql

I currently have a table A

```
+--------+---------+
| eventID | hostID |
+--------+---------+
|     62 |       1 |
|     61 |       5 |
+--------+---------+
```

And Table B

```
+--------+---------+
| userID | eventID |
+--------+---------+
|      1 |      61 |
|      5 |      61 |
+--------+---------+
```

I want to create a query where it Left Join table A and Table B and check if my table A eventID and hostID exist in table B for evnetID and userID. If it exist, stauts will be 1, else,it will be 0. 
To understand more visually, I want my output to be like this:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+
|eventID | hostID   | status     | 
+--------+-----------+------------+
|     62 | 1         |          0 |      
|     61 | 5         |          1 |    
+--------+-----------+------------
```

As you can see,eventID =  62 and hostID =  1 doesnt exist in table B, so stauts will be 0 while eventID = 61 while hostID  = 5 exist so status will be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more efficiently solved using an `EXISTS` expression:

```
SELECT eventID, hostID,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                         FROM b 
                         WHERE b.eventID = a.eventID
                           AND b.userID = a.hostID) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS status
FROM a
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXxszLYe73yC4MDjoECKsy/1)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*,
       (case when b.eventId is null then 0 else 1 end)
from a left join
     b
     on a.eventID = b.eventID and a.hostId = b.userId
```